# Binding behaviour on lightning components with ui:inputText/Checkbox components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community-builder

I'm currently building a lightning component for a community builder portal.
The whole series of components is reasonably complex but nothing extreme (it's a wizard).

To make things easier I'm using a wrapper class with several objects and sub objects in. Again, it's more than just a simple wrapper class but nothing too complex.

When I bind a field using ui:inputText or ui:inputCheckbox, for example, it appears to be binding (in some cases, not all) to a non-existent field one level up the wrapper class object structure.

Looking at the screenshot below you can see 'Patient_Information_Checked__c'. This field sits on the appointment object. However, as you can see the value is being bound one level up (line 3 on the image) so when I try to save it doesn't submit the correct value...

[image: Console Output]

Here is a shortened version of my component code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.treatments}" var="treatmentWrapper">
    <div>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!treatmentWrapper.isSelected == true}">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox-patientCheckReferrer" value="{!treatmentWrapper.appointment.Patient_Information_Checked__c}" class="checkbox"/>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly? Or is there a known issue with using the ui:input series of fields and binding? I also tried using the lightning:input and I experience the same issue.

My workaround at the moment is duplicate the field as a String or Boolean in the outer most layer of my wrapper then copy in the value to the correct field on save... This isn't ideal for many obvious reasons.

*** EDIT

At the request for more information, here are full code samples on how to reproduce the issue:

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="CommunitiesReferralPatientConfController">

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="treatments" type="TreatmentWrapper[]"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.treatments}" var="treatmentWrapper">
    <div>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!treatmentWrapper.isSelected == true}">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox-patientCheckReferrer" value="{!treatmentWrapper.appointment.Patient_Information_Checked__c}" class="checkbox"/>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>

<ui:button aura:id="nextButton" label="Next" press="{!c.nextStep}" class="slds-button slds-button--brand nextButton"/></aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    var grabReferral = component.get("c.getReferral");
    grabReferral.setParams({ referralId : component.get("v.recordId")});

    grabReferral.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var treatments = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
        component.set("v.treatments", treatments);
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(grabReferral);
},

nextStep : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('nextStep');

    var treatments = component.get("v.treatments");

    console.log(treatments);
}
})
```

Apex Class

```
@AuraEnabled
public static TreatmentWrapper getReferral(String referralId)
{
    System.debug('#### getDraftReferral');
    ContactHelper ch = new ContactHelper();

    List<TreatmentWrapper> wrapper = new List<TreatmentWrapper>();


    List<Treatment__c> queriedTreatments = [SELECT Id, Name,                                                    
                                                (SELECT Id, Active_Appointment__c, FROM__c, Patient_Information_Checked__c FROM Calendar_Entries__r WHERE Active_Appointment__c = true)                                                      
                                            FROM Treatment__c WHERE Referral__c = :referralId];

    for(Treatment__c treatment : queriedTreatments)
    {
        TreatmentWrapper tw = new TreatmentWrapper();
        tw.isSelected = true;
        tw.theTreatment = tw;

        for(Calendar_Entry__c entry : treatment.Calendar_Entries__r)
        {
            tw.appointment = entry;            
        } 

        wrapper.add(tw);
    }         
}
```

Wrapper Class

```
public with sharing class TreatmentWrapper
{
    @AuraEnabled public Integer treatmentIndex {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Boolean isSelected {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String treatmentFamily {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled public Treatment__c theTreatment {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled public Calendar_Entry__c appointment {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String appointmentNote {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: To get more feedback you should share a minimal viable amount of code usable to copy-paste-replicate the issue for others.

Comment: Hi @UweHeim I've now updated the original question to contain a full sample of the source code. This definitely reproduces the issue I'm having. Unfortunately there are some custom objects but I expect you could swap them out for standard ones (accounts, opportunities, etc). I hope that helps with anyone trying to offer and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in the lightning component code:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.treatments))}">
<aura:iteration items="{!v.treatments}" var="treatmentWrapper">
    <div>          
<aura:if isTrue="{!treatmentWrapper.isSelected == true}">         
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox-patientCheckReferrer" value="{!treatmentWrapper.appointment.Patient_Information_Checked__c}" class="checkbox" change="{!c.setValue}"/>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
</aura:if>
```

Try implement the above component code first and if it doesn't work either, then include the onchange event on checkbox and do the following code:

Controller:

```
setValue:function(component,event,helper){
//  write code to manually set the value

}
```